# How to download large data file from web using request module?

Tags: python, download, request

I am using python to download files from webpage, and after I submit the request, I get the headers like below:

```
r.headers=
{'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="report20160619-013623.csv";',
 'Content-Transfer-Encoding': 'binary', 'Expires': '0',
'Keep-Alive': 'timeout=5, max=100', 'Server': 'Apache',
'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'Keep-Alive', 'Pragma': 'public',
'Cache-Control': 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, private',
'Date': 'Sun, 19 Jun 2016 06:35:18 GMT', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'}
```

I  can directly download the file from webpage which is around 50 megabytes, but when I use python request to do so, it does not work. It returns:

```
r = sss.get(url, stream=True, headers=my_headers)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.8.1-py2.7.egg/requests/sessions.py", line 480, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.8.1-py2.7.egg/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.8.1-py2.7.egg/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.8.1-py2.7.egg/requests/adapters.py", line 426, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))
```

And here is my URL: 
https://aosreports2.corp.XXX.com/DOSSIER/?period=Date+Range&report_period=Current&start_date=2016-02-28&end_date=2016-03-15&data=bookings&low_val=&high_val=&search_var=none&search_vals=&run=Download&m%5B%5D=Gross+USD+Value&m%5B%5D=Attach+BTB+USD&m%5B%5D=Net+Units&r%5B%5D=Channel&r%5B%5D=Region&r%5B%5D=Country+GLOBALLOBS&r%5B%5D=Order+Method&r%5B%5D=Cancel+Reason&r%5B%5D=Cancel+Reason+Type&r%5B%5D=Product+LOB&r%5B%5D=Product+Sub+Family&r%5B%5D=Product+Class&f%5B%5D=Sales+District+Category&f%5B%5D=Channel&f%5B%5D=Finance+Region&f%5B%5D=Order+Product+Type&salesDistCat%5B%5D=Sales&chnl%5B%5D=ONL&finRgn%5B%5D=Greater+China&ordProdType%5B%5D=STANDARD+ORDER&radio%5B%5D=a_v&altTax%5B%5D=a_v&bpItem%5B%5D=a_v&bpSubItem%5B%5D=a_v&cpnId%5B%5D=a_v&createTool%5B%5D=a_v&lnecreateTool%5B%5D=a_v&crosBrdr%5B%5D=a_v&csfID%5B%5D=a_v&custGrp%5B%5D=a_v&dsCt%5B%5D=a_v&emeaShip1%5B%5D=a_v&finInd%5B%5D=a_v&giftCd%5B%5D=a_v&giftEligInd%5B%5D=a_v&multiCrdInd%5B%5D=a_v&iCustNt%5B%5D=a_v&busAdd%5B%5D=a_v&busAddItm%5B%5D=a_v&iphLk%5B%5D=a_v&itmShpcnd%5B%5D=a_v&prtlDel%5B%5D=a_v&oneClick%5B%5D=a_v&payId%5B%5D=a_v&persInd%5B%5D=a_v&preAuth%5B%5D=a_v&qotInd%5B%5D=a_v&Requote_Ind%5B%5D=a_v&refurbInd%5B%5D=a_v&replOrder%5B%5D=a_v&retailStrId%5B%5D=a_v&runRate%5B%5D=a_v&salesQuote%5B%5D=a_v&slsOrg%5B%5D=a_v&shipCondCd%5B%5D=a_v&sapNte%5B%5D=a_v&tmsFlg%5B%5D=a_v&shipFlg%5B%5D=a_v&preFlg%5B%5D=a_v&sigRsn%5B%5D=a_v&shiPlnt%5B%5D=a_v&shipQuote%5B%5D=a_v&smbTierGrp%5B%5D=a_v&soldCust%5B%5D=a_v&sftID%5B%5D=a_v&thdPtypic%5B%5D=a_v&volOrdQty%5B%5D=a_v&vatflg%5B%5D=a_v&multiAdd%5B%5D=a_v&shipCompFlg%5B%5D=a_v&woHld%5B%5D=a_v

So my question is how to download the large data file with python request?thanks

Comment: Are you sure that's a working url? I'm getting a 404.

Comment: Hi, SvbZ3r0, I mask the company's name. And also I need to login before I go to this url, so you can't access to this url anyway. And I have login successfully with python request, and also successfully request the URL by python. But I don't know how to solve the errors. If you need any information for that session? I can show you from chrome developer tool.

Comment: Well.. `ConnectionError` is raised when your connection is faulty, or you can't connect to the server.. I'm not sure but maybe they're blocking bots. Have you tried setting the `user-agent` header to Chrome's or Firefox's before sending the request?

Comment: @SvbZ3r0, yes, I did.    `my_headers = {
    'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept' : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding' : 'identity, deflate, compress, gzip',
    'Accept-Language' : 'zh-CN,zh;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,zh-TW;q=0.4'
}
sss     = requests.Session()
r       = sss.get(cs_url, headers = my_headers)`